# How to set height of ViewPager regardless of device screen height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have a tab layout in `MainActivity` which has `ViewPager`, I am also adding bottom navigation to `MainActivity`, I want `ViewPager` to be of height that it touches the top of the bottom navigation.

Here is my main activity layout

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10sp"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />



    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

     <include layout="@layout/bottom_nav"></include>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Currently `ViewPager` spans full height behind bottom navigation bar. I want my `Viewpager` to be like below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinearLayout` as a parent layout and also set weight to your `ViewPager`. It would work in your case. Check below code.

```
 <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10sp"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />



    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

     <include layout="@layout/bottom_nav"></include>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this solves the problem but I'm not sure why I was using CoordinatorLayout in the first place but thanks.

Comment: @vikasdevde If it does help you then please accept my post a answer so it would be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Use Liner layout as a parent layout after co-ordinate layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10sp"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
<include layout="@layout/bottom_nav"></include>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```